# Getting mouse position relative to center of rotated image

Tags: javascript, canvas, trigonometry

I'm trying to write some code that allows a user to arbitrarily drag an image around a canvas, resize the image, and rotate the image using their mouse. I am having some trouble with my trigonometry.

All points of interest are relative to the center of the image. In the illustration below the mouse is at the absolute position **850, 400** (relative to the canvas' upper left). Since there is no rotation I can easily figure out that the mouse is in the relative position **250, 0** (relative to the center of the image).

[image]

After I rotate the image 270° and put the mouse in the same position, the absolute is **600, 150**. The relative position is exactly the same as it was before the rotation though (**250, 0**).

[image]

Given the absolute coordinates of the image's center point, it's rotation, and the absolute position of the mouse, **how can I determine the transformed, rotated coordinates of the mouse relative to the center of the image?**

I've tried many things and attempted to adapt answers from similar StackOverflow questions. My current attempt uses a Matrix class someone published in a Gist.

```
layerRelativePoint(x, y, layer){
    var radians = layer.rotation * (Math.PI/180);
    var matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.translate(-layer.x, -layer.y);
    matrix.rotate(radians);
    var [x, y] = matrix.transformPoint(x, y);
    return {x, y};
}
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/T9XCfpZVlMWLMY67bOvW?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer on [Math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3244477/311032).

Here is the implementation I came up with:

```
/**
 * Translate a point's absolute coordinates to it's coordinates 
 * relative to a possibly rotated center point
 * -------------------------------------------------------------
 * @param {number} absPointX - The absolute x ordinate of the point to translate
 * @param {number} absPointY - The absolute y ordinate of the point to translate
 * @param {number} centerX - The absolute x ordinate of the center point of rotation
 * @param {number} centerY - The absolute y ordinate of the center point of rotation
 * @param {number} rotationDegrees - The angle of rotation in degrees
 * @returns {x, y} - The translated point's coordinates
 */
function translatePoint(absPointX, absPointY, centerX, centerY, rotationDegrees=0) {
    // Get coordinates relative to center point
    absPointX -= centerX;
    absPointY -= centerY;

    // Convert degrees to radians
    var radians = rotationDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);

    // Translate rotation
    var cos = Math.cos(radians);
    var sin = Math.sin(radians);
    var x = (absPointX * cos) + (absPointY * sin);
    var y = (-absPointX * sin) + (absPointY * cos);

    // Round to nearest hundredths place
    x = Math.floor(x * 100) / 100;
    y = Math.floor(y * 100) / 100;

    return {x, y};
}
```